# How to create a new patch set in gerrit

Tags: magit

I'm using magit and magit-gerrit, for easy changes, and reviews it works well, but I cannot figure out how to add a new patchset to a change that it is in gerrit

Comment: It might be better to ask the author of magit-gerrit directly. The author might not use this site and maybe there are also only few of its users on this site.

Comment: If you actually did what I suggested, then you should reproduce the answer that was given to you here, in your own words.

Comment: A little bit late but I will do it

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about gerrit (yet), but after just scrolling through `magit-gerrit.el` and noticing that new reviews are created using `magit-gerrit-create-review`, which uses `magit-gerrit-push-review`, which simply does `git push ...`, I would assume that you can (and apparently are expected to) just push to the same branch as before using regular git/magit push commands.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Tarsius. A simple gerrit-push-review does the trick. For this answer I believe that is pretty important to understand [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22557/add-change-to-a-previous-commit-with-magit) answer as well

Let's supose that we have something like this:

```
Head:     master add important line
Merge:    origin/master little nonsense

Reviews (1)
25249     add important line                                                                                                               Antonio Querol

Unmerged into origin/master (1)
5c960ac master add important line
```

Then the reviewer told me that I need to add a paths set to this line

```
modified   presentation-text/Entornos-y-despliegues.org
@@ -509,6 +509,7 @@ Help IT with this things and the deployment will be never like today
 * vamos a ver si esto funciona
 * creo el patch set y un peque√±o cambio => mira como si pongo un cambio
 * a√±ado una peque√±a tonteria
+* Let's add this a very important line
 * Q & A
```

Since is the alst commit I made the shanges in the code and then ammend it, like this:

Stage the changes and then over the changes press c and then a to ammend the last commit. Edit what you want, the message of the commit or type C-c C-c to finish it.

Then over the commit push R and P so now in gerrit you can see the path for the line

```
Antonio Querol
Uploaded patch set 1.
9:40 AM
Antonio Querol
Uploaded patch set 2.
9:48 AM
Powered by Gerrit Code Review (2.10-rc1) | Report Bug | Press '?' to view keyboard shortcuts
```

I hope this helps